# How to know if recycler view is scrolled up or down in pre 23 api

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I have seen a lot of answer of this question, and also implemented one of them, but the issue is it does not work as per expectation on start, but after a while it starts working fine.

This is my code.

```
rvCalender.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    float initialY, finalY;
    boolean isScrollingUp;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        switch(action) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                initialY = event.getY();


        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                finalY = event.getY();

                if (initialY < finalY) {
                    Log.d("SCROLLED", "Scrolling up");
                    isScrollingUp = true;
                    isScrolledDownward=false;
                } else if (initialY > finalY) {
                    Log.d("SCROLLED", "Scrolling down");
                    isScrolledDownward= true;
                    isScrollingUp = false;
                }
            default:
        }


        return false;
    }
});
```

So once i start scrolling `recyclerview`, it keeps returning `isScrollDownward` false, but after scrolling 7-8 items, it starts giving me `isScrollDownward` true, which is fine, but i am unable to understand why it does not work correctly on start.

or is this correct way of getting user scroll direction, or there is some other better way available.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an OnScrollListener (introduced in API version 22).  Here's an example:

```
public class RecyclerViewOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        //Scroll down
        if (dy > 0)
        {
            // your logic here
        }

        //Scroll up
        if (dy < 0)
        {
            // your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

And you can attach it like this:

```
rvCalender.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewOnScrollListener());
```

The issue with the touch event is that recyclerviews have a concept of acceleration.  So your finger might move up slightly as you draw it away and you'll get an up touch that the scrolling view itself ends up basically ignoring.  The scroll listener tracks what the view is actually doing.